# request.body as it is undefined - Erro no request.body

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, autenticação, request

Quando vou realizar um teste de flash message em meu formulário o site cai e aparece o seguinte erro:
const { name, email, password, confirmpassword } = request.body
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'request.body' as it is undefined.

Estou usando a biblioteca flash() junto ao express para fazer a verificação se as senhas do cadastro são iguais e assim registrar o usuário com sucesso. Porém, o código não apresenta a resposta, cai e apresenta o erro.

Código do Controller:

const User = require('../models/User');

// Never save the raw password in the database. We use a library to encrypt the password:
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

module.exports = class AuthController {

```
static login(request, response) {
    response.render('auth/login')
}

static register(request, response) {
    response.render('auth/register')
}

static async registerPost(request, response) {
   
    const { name, email, password, confirmpassword } = request.body
    // Password Match validation:
    if (password != confirmpassword) {
        
        request.flash('message', 'Senhas não conferem. Tente novamente.');
        response.render('auth/register');

        return;

    }  
}
```

}

// Código da main e do input register em handlebars e html:

Thoughts

```
    <a href="/" id="logo"><img src="/img/thoughts.png" alt="thoughts"></a>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Pensamentos</a></li>
        <li><a href="/login">Entrar</a></li>
        <li><a href="/register">Registrar</a></li>
    </ul>

</nav>
</header>
<div class="container">
    {{#if message}}
    <div class="message">
        {{message}}
    </div>
    {{/if}}

    {{{ body }}}
</div>
<footer>
    <p><span>Thoughts</span> &copy; Desenvolvido por Ronaldo Rios Espíndola</p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Possível solução:**

O **express.json()** é um middleware que extrai o corpo de uma solicitação HTTP em formato JSON e o disponibiliza para a aplicação na propriedade request.body. Isso é útil quando você quer acessar dados enviados pelo cliente em formato JSON, como em uma solicitação POST que envia dados de um formulário.

O express.json() foi introduzido a partir da versão 4.16.0 do Express.

Por exemplo, aqui está como você pode usar o middleware **express.json** para extrair o corpo de uma request:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/', function(request, response){
  console.log(request.body);
   response.send(request.body);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Se você estiver usando uma versão anterior do Express, você pode usar o módulo body-parser para realizar a mesma tarefa.

Por exemplo, aqui está como você pode usar o body-parser para extrair o corpo de uma request:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express()

// Configure o body-parser para ler o corpo da solicitação em formato JSON
app.use(bodyParser.json())

// Crie uma rota que aceita solicitações POST
app.post('/', function(request, response){
  console.log(request.body)      // seu JSON
  response.send(request.body)
})

app.listen(3000)
```